# @CrossOrigin not adding Access-Control-Allow-Origin Header

Tags: java, spring, cors

I have simply added `@CrossOrigin` annotation like this:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:9090", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("*")
```

But it is not adding any header related to CORS in response.

Should I have to do something more to get it work?

Thanks in advance

[image]

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9090' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Comment: How are you testing this? Your request does not look like cross-origin `OPTIONS` request but rather the regular request that follows the `OPTIONS` request.

Comment: I am using AJAX request for that, It was working fine when I implemented OncePerRequestFilter but now I have upgraded Spring so I want to use @CrossOrigin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this issue, the problem was that I was defining
`<mvc:annotation-driven/>` tag in `dispacher-servlet.xml` instead of `app-context.xml` and the second thing was that the schema URLs were not correct fot this mvc tag.
You can check structure of Spring-MVC and Beans in intelliJ Idea by opening Spring tab menu.